# Facebook drop iOS SDK 2 support in June 2013

Tags: facebook, sdk

Facebook announced it will stop support for SDK 2 in June 2013.
Can somebody confirm that facebook connect using sdk 2 for iOS will still work after that date?

I will not be able to update my ios app before june.